# Box2D via libGDX: How to create one MouseJoint per body for separate Android touches?

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx, physics

What's up everyone,

Thanks for your time.

I am making a Pong clone, and I want to restrict Box2D to two MouseJoints maximum; one MouseJoint maximum per paddle. The MouseJoints should be created only if one of the user's two touches lands within either of the two paddle's boundaries.

I am getting a weird result with my code. If my first touch lands within the left paddle and my second touch lands outside of either paddle, a second MouseJoint is created on the left paddle (see attached image).

Note: In addition to the two MouseJoints on the left paddle, there are two PrismaticJoints in the image; one attached to each paddle.

[image]

To no avail, I've tried all of the algorithms that I could think of or adapt from other people's code.

If a code solution example or link could be posted, I would be much obliged.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{

/*========some variables and methods omitted for clarity========*/


/*multiple mouse joint experiment*/
public MouseJoint mouseJoint[] = new MouseJoint[2];    
Body hitBody[] = new Body[2];
Body tempBody;

public MyScreen(Pong game) {
    this.game = game;
}        

/*---------------------Screen interface methods--------------------------*/
//methods omitted for clarity
/*---------------------end Screen interface methods----------------------*/

/*---------------------InputProcessor interface methods------------------*/
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {                                       
                testPoint.set(screenX, screenY, 0);
                camera.unproject(testPoint);

                // ask the world which bodies are within the given
                // bounding box around the mouse pointer
                hitBody[pointer] = null;

                world.QueryAABB(callback, testPoint.x - 1.0f, testPoint.y - 1.0f, testPoint.x + 1.0f, testPoint.y + 1.0f);
                hitBody[pointer] = tempBody;

                // if we hit something we create a new mouse joint
                // and attach it to the hit body.
                if (hitBody[pointer] != null) {

                    MouseJointDef def = new MouseJointDef();
                    def.bodyA = groundBody;
                    def.bodyB = hitBody[pointer];
                    def.collideConnected = true;                                                 
                    def.target.set(hitBody[pointer].getPosition().x, hitBody[pointer].getPosition().y);
                    def.maxForce = 3000.0f * hitBody[pointer].getMass();

                    mouseJoint[pointer] = (MouseJoint)world.createJoint(def);
                    hitBody[pointer].setAwake(true);
                } else {

                }
                return false;                 
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) { 
    if (mouseJoint[pointer] != null) {
        world.destroyJoint(mouseJoint[pointer]);
        mouseJoint[pointer] = null;
    }
    return false;
}

/**a temporary vector for delta target destination during touchDragged() method**/
Vector2 target = new Vector2();

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    if (mouseJoint[pointer] != null) {
        camera.unproject(testPoint.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
        mouseJoint[pointer].setTarget(target.set(testPoint.x, testPoint.y));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}
    /*----------------end InputProcessor interface methods------------------*/

/*------------------------helper methods------------------------------------*/
    /*android screen touch vector for a mouse joint*/
    Vector3 testPoint = new Vector3(); //we instantiate this vector and the callback here so we don't irritate the GC
    QueryCallback callback = new QueryCallback() {
       @Override public boolean reportFixture (Fixture fixture) {
          // if the hit fixture's body is the ground body
          // we ignore it
          if (fixture.getBody() == groundBody) return true;

          if (fixture.testPoint(testPoint.x, testPoint.y)) {
              tempBody = fixture.getBody();
                return false;
          } else
                return true;
       }
    };          
/*------------------------end helper methods-------------------------------*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see the `tempBody` is never reset to null. What that means is that the first time you touch the pad it sets the `tempBody` to the touched paddle and then when you press outside the body the callback will not find a new body but not reset the `testBody` to null, so when you assign `testBody` to `hitBody[pointer]` it is setting it to the first paddle.

The way your touch down function should look like is:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {                                       
            testPoint.set(screenX, screenY, 0);
            camera.unproject(testPoint);

            // ask the world which bodies are within the given
            // bounding box around the mouse pointer
            hitBody[pointer] = null;

            world.QueryAABB(callback, testPoint.x - 1.0f, testPoint.y - 1.0f, testPoint.x + 1.0f, testPoint.y + 1.0f);
            hitBody[pointer] = tempBody;

            // if we hit something we create a new mouse joint
            // and attach it to the hit body.
            if (hitBody[pointer] != null) {

                MouseJointDef def = new MouseJointDef();
                def.bodyA = groundBody;
                def.bodyB = hitBody[pointer];
                def.collideConnected = true;                                                 
                def.target.set(hitBody[pointer].getPosition().x, hitBody[pointer].getPosition().y);
                def.maxForce = 3000.0f * hitBody[pointer].getMass();

                mouseJoint[pointer] = (MouseJoint)world.createJoint(def);
                hitBody[pointer].setAwake(true);
            } else {

            }
            tempBody = null;

            return false;
```

}

This way the tempBody is always reset to null after use.