# How can I implement multiple touch in Box2D?

Tags: java, libgdx, jbox2d

I want to move two bodies on a android phone using two separate touch's, Is this possible?

Comment: solved using ,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944451/box2d-via-libgdx-how-to-create-one-mousejoint-per-body-for-separate-android-tou

Answer (score 0):

You can get coordinates of first and second touch with following methods

```
int firstX = Gdx.input.getX(0);
int firstY = Gdx.input.getY(0);
int secondX = Gdx.input.getX(1);
int secondY = Gdx.input.getY(1);
```

Use them to move your objects.

You can read more in [libgdx documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Polling)

Comment: I'm using a mouse joint to move the box2d bodies, will It work with it? Also do you have any examples?

Thanks for the response:).

Comment: You can create one mouse joint for every finger that touched the screen. I couldn't found any examples with multitouch but you can look for pretty good example [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594620/how-to-use-the-mouse-joint-in-android).

Comment: Thanks for you're help, I used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944451/box2d-via-libgdx-how-to-create-one-mousejoint-per-body-for-separate-android-tou to solve it.